# Why apps are installed to my iPad and not to my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, ipad

Whenever I press "Get" to download an app in iTunes (either on iOS or Windows OS), apps are installed in my iPad and never to my iPhone.

However, after "Get" becomes "Downloaded" and I go to App Store on my iPhone, I see a down-arrow in a middle of a cloud. When I press it, then the app is installed in the phone.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > iTunes & App Store
Enable Automatic downloads for Apps

[image]

Also make sure that 'Automatically install new apps' is enabled in iTunes
*window in picture artificially shrunk to save space*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, in fact, this option is enabled already in my "iTunes & App Stores" settings.

Comment: added iTunes option too